# How do I get the http header when consuming JSON using jackson.

Tags: java, jackson

I am using jackson to consume JSON from a REST endpoint.

Its working fine. I like to know how do I get the HTTP header information. Here is my code.

```
public AuthenticatedUser getAuthenticatedUser(){
    try {
        AuthenticatedUser user = mapper.readValue(authenticationURL,AuthenticatedUser.class);

        return user;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.writeExceptionToLog(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I wanted to check for 200 status etc.

Comment: What web-framework do you use? The JSON and jackson ObjectMapper itself has nothing to do with the http endpoint.